# Allow more than one serializer_class in one ModelViewSet class Django REST

Tags: django, swagger

How do I define more than one serializer_class in one ModelViewSet? I have four functions in one ModelViewSet, and any positions have their serializer. How can I place four serializers in one serializer_class?

Answer (score 0):

You can override `get_serializer_class`.

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    # insert your logic here, this is just an example.
    some_option = self.request.GET.get("some_option", None)
    if some_option:
        return SomeSerializer

    return AnotherSerializer
```